# SAS: Custom Week format that starts weeks on Thursdays?

Tags: date, sas, format

Hi I was wondering if anyone knows how I can create a custom SAS week format that starts weeks on Thursdays rather than Mondays/Sundays like the default formats do (the descriptors U/V/W only allow you to start weeks on Mondays/Sundays)?

Comment: Week of the YEAR? Week of the MONTH?  How do you plan to use this FORMAT?  Or do you really want a FUNCTION instead?  Please show example data as input and what output you want from the example data.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use arithmetic.

So if you wanted to number the weeks of year you could just find the first Thursday of the year and divide the difference in days by 7 .

```
data test;
  input day yymmdd10.;
  downame=put(day,downame.-L);
  first_thursday=nwkdom(1,5,1,year(day));
  format first_thursday day yymmdd10.;
  week = int((day-first_thursday+7)/7);
cards;
2023-01-04
2023-01-05
2023-01-06
2023-01-07
2023-01-12
2022-12-31
;
```

Results

```
                                      first_
Obs           day    downame        thursday    week

 1     2023-01-04    Wednesday    2023-01-05      0
 2     2023-01-05    Thursday     2023-01-05      1
 3     2023-01-06    Friday       2023-01-05      1
 4     2023-01-07    Saturday     2023-01-05      1
 5     2023-01-12    Thursday     2023-01-05      2
 6     2022-12-31    Saturday     2022-01-06     52
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function-based format.

Example:

```
options cmplib=_null_ nocenter nodate nonumber;

proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.format;
  function thursdays(date) ;
    foy = intnx('year',date,0) ;
    return (intck('week.5', foy, date));
  endfunc;
run;

options cmplib = work.funcs;


proc format;
  value weekt low-high = [thursdays()];
run;


data dates;
  do date = '01jan2018'd to '01may2023'd ;
    date2 = date;
    date3 = date;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc print data=dates label;
  format date weekt.;     label date = 'Week by Thursday';
  format date2 yymmdd10.;
  format date3 downame.;

  where month(date) = 1;
run;
```

[image]